# Audio output automatically changes to HDMI Audio Output when starting a game

Tags: audio, hdmi, amd-radeon

I am not sure what causing it. I tried to change some settings for the graphic card, but it didn't work.

```
Graphic card: Sapphire 7870 XT.
Motherboard: GA-H77-D3H.
```

At first, I thought it's ATI Catalyst Control Center changing my audio output. I changed there the default audio output, but still when I open a game (Starcraft or Borderlands for example) my PC changes the audio output to AMD HD Audio - HDMI.

I haven't yet found someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Check your Sound control panel settings. Mine has an Audio tab where I can select the Default device for sound playback. My soundcard also installed its own Mixer application which can be started by name under Programs.

Comment: I tried to change some settings on VIA HD Deck, nothing changed. Changed default audio output on Catalyst control center, nothing changed. Is there a debugger for something like this? I am losing my mind :O

Comment: You may be able to uninstall _just_ the HDMI Audio Driver. There's a Change button next to AMD Catalyst Install Manager in my Windows Add or Remove Programs control panel. After selecting it and picking Custom, a list of components is presented and one of them is the HDMI Audio Driver. I didn't take it any further.

Comment: The thing is, I do use my HDMI for TV. I'll try to reinstall Catalyst & VIA HD Deck, hope it helps...